# Probability density function of a particle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have a probability density function $f(x)= ce^{-|x|}$ for the location of a particle on the real line, where $c$ is a constant. How do we determine the value of $k$ such that it is equally likely that the particle will be found inside and outside the interval $(-k,k)$?

Any hints will be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried writing down formulas for the probabilities of finding the particle within the interval and outside of the interval?

Answer (score 2):

The value of $c$ can be calculated with
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx=1.$$
Let $k>0$. What you now need is
$$\int_{-k}^k f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{-k} f(x)dx+\int_k^{\infty}f(x)dx=2\int_{k}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$